# Dynamically change upload location based on Model name in Django

Tags: django

I have this model:

```
class Photos (models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Purpose = models.CharField(default='None', max_length=10)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'photos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

This model houses all of the Photos that gets uploaded to the site.  I have three other models that refer to it:

```
class Member(Models.Model):
     ...(various fields)
     Photos = models.ManytoManyForeignKey(Photos)

class Unit(models.Model):
     ...(various fields)
     Photos = models.ManytoManyForeignKey(Photos)

class avatar(models.Model):
     ...(various fields)
     Photos = models.ForeignKey(Photos)
```

My question is where the files are located.  I know I can add `uploaded-to:` parameter in the PHotos class, but is there a way that I can specialize which folder to go to based on the referring model?

such as `uploaded-to: '/avatars/'` when the class avatar is engaged?  or to `/Member-Photos/` folder for the Members class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could since [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) can take a function. So basically, you could use something like,

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('/media/%s/' % instance.__class__.__name__, filename) 

class Photos (models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    ...
```

This will dynamically append your models class names (eg. `avatar`,`Member`,etc.)

**EDIT**

If ever you want to customize the names returned depending on the model instance, I'd create a `dict` that maps those values.

```
path_mapping = {'avatars':'avatars','Member':'Member-Photos'}

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    try:
        path = path_mapping[instance.__class__.__name__]
    except KeyError:
        path = 'Unknown'
    return os.path.join('/media/%s/' %path , filename) 

class Photos (models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    ...
```

Note that this is not the only way of achieving this. I just find it maintainable and readable. If ever you didn't implement a custom path in your mapping `dict`, `'Unknown'` will be used.

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thanks much!!

Comment: sorry, type(instance) returns: <class 'svcrecord.models.Photos'>.  How do I fix that?

Comment: @arcee123 Let me know if it now suits your needs.

Comment: Yes.  I will work with this.  I thank you very much.

Comment: you have an extra parenthesis(")") in your code at the end of the `path = ` line, however, I think this will work.  My problem right now, is I have to redo my forms to ensure that the instance is 'member' or 'unit' when sending photos in.